# Adding "Dynamic" roles to users discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that does a lot of things, I got most of the, down but an issue I am having is trying to let someone add any role they want. I have commands that give users specific roles, here's an example

```
@commands.command()
async def aroleStreamer(self, ctx, user : discord.Member):
    Streamer = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Streamer")
    await user.add_roles(Streamer)
    await ctx.send(f"{user} now has {Streamer}")
```

this works and all, but I want it so that people can choose a certain role they want so I don't have to make code for every role that we make. I've tried this code:

```
@commands.command()
 async def arole(self, ctx, *, role : discord.Guild.roles, user : discord.Member):
    xrole = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=(role))
    await user.add_roles(xrole)
    await ctx.send(f"{user} now has {xrole}")
```

but I've had no luck. the error I get is: `Converting to "property" failed for parameter "role".` Does anyone have code that can help me?

Edit: I realized I used the remove role command, changed it to the add role command

Comment: Is there a reason why you have `role` in parentheses in the first line of the function? I believe that might be your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be typehinted to simply `discord.Role`

```py
async def artole(self, ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.User):
```